# How to create a data store with a dictionary of objects holding a generic field

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around C#'s generics and I'm either missing some piece of info or I'm going about it all wrong. I have a class called WatchedVariable:

```
class WatchedVariable<T>
{
    private T Data { get; set; }

    public WatchedVariable(T initVal)
    {
        Data = initVal;
    }

    public T GetVal()
    {
        return Data;
    }
    public void SetData(T newVal)
    {
        Data = newVal;
    }
}
```

The point of this class is to hold a value that can be of any type as I do not know what the type will be at runtime.

I also have a DataStore used to hold a Dictionary of these WatchedVariable objects:

```
class DataStore
{
    private Dictionary<string, WatchedVariable<T>> _store;

    public DataStore()
    {
        _store = new Dictionary<string, WatchedVariable>();
    }
    
    public void AddToStore(string varname, WatchedVariable variable)
    {
        _store.Add(varname, variable);
    }

    public string GetFromStore(string key)
    {
        return _store[key].GetVal();
    }

    public void ChangeValInStore(string key, string newVal)
    {
        _store[key].SetData(newVal);
    }
}
```

My question is how do I go about setting up the _store Dictionary so that it can take these generic WatchedVariable objects. Currently the compiler is mad at me for placing  next to the WatchedVariable for the _store Dictionary value. I want to avoid placing  on the DataStore class itself since that would essentially lock me into a specific type, which I don't want to do. Again, either I'm going about this all wrong or something I'm just missing here.

Comment: "avoid placing on" -- placing what? This is not clear.

Comment: As in DataStore<T>. I can see how my wording is confusing there.

Comment: *I do not know what the type will be at runtime* - that might be the bit where it falls down - generics aren't a run time thing. It's a way of writing code where the compiler can fill in the missing part of the typing when you write other code that uses the generic code. Microsoft wrote `List<T>` not knowing what type of objects you'll shove in your list. You create a Person and make a `List<Person>`, the compiler can know "oh, this list holds Person, which means that the `public T GetThingAtIndex(int)` method shall return a Person. It's not a way of delaying type decisioning until runtime

Answer (score 1):

> I do not know what the type will be at runtime.

This is beyond the ability of Generics. Generics are specifically there to allow you to put in any type while maintaining Compile Time Type safety.

There is some leeway with co- and contravariance (which *imitates* [casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) within the same class heirarchy for the generic type), but maintaining compile time type safety was a important reason for their existence.

Otherwise we would just use the equivalent of `List<Object>` everwhere and call it a day.

Comment: Thanks to you and Caius for this info. I'm still fresh with C# and some of this info is still not ingrained yet.

Comment: @GlCo No problem. (Compile Time) Type safety as a incredibly important thing in .NET. It is really hard to get rid off. And is really a thing you should never try to get rid off in the first place. The PHP and JS example are on that way: http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/12/24/0747-melodys-guide-to-programming-languages/